# GLSL buffer with multiple arbitrary sized variables

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I'm trying to bind a storage buffer of object structs containing multiple variables of different types so that I can access them in my vertex shader.

Struct:

```
struct Object
{
    vec2 vertices[4];
};
```

```
layout(std140, set = 0, binding = 0) buffer ObjectBlock
{
    Object objects[];
};
```

Using the code above, although I am able to compile the shader and get the Vulkan program running, the values from the array variable `vertices` are completely different from the values I inputted. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking about here. Are you asking if structs, or arrays of structs, work at all in SSBOs? Why would you think they wouldn't? Also, what would "a separate uniform buffer" have to do with storage buffers?

Comment: @NicolBolas I redrafted my question. I'm not sure how else I can ask this question.

Comment: "*`layout(std140`*" Are you sure you meant that?

Comment: I'm not too sure what that does... I've used this code with `mat4 matrix;` as the variable before, so I assumed it would work if I changed it to `vec2 vertices[4]` as well.